# pytest (or unittest) not working when a source file has a dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I'm not sure why this is so difficult to get going, but I'm new to Python and I'm trying to get any unit test framework to run tests, but if I test a file that has a dependency, I get "Module Not Found". I've seen similar posts on SO but none of them solve my problem. I'm using Python on Windows.

The project structure is like this:

```
some_project
---- my_app
     ---- my_app.py
     ---- my_lib.py
---- test
     ---- test_my_app.py
```

In my_app.py, I have something like:

```
 def say_hello(name: str) -> str:
         return f"Hello, {name}"
```

In test_my_app.py, I have:

```
from my_app.my_app import say_hello
def test_say_hello():
    assert say_hello("Bob") == "Hello, Bob"
```

Then when I run pytest, everything works and the test passes. But if I add a dependency into the mix by including my_lib.py:

In my_lib.py:

```
def concat(s1: str, s2: str) -> str:
    return f"{s1}, {s2}"
```

Then in my_app.py:

```
from my_lib import concat
def say_hello(name: str) -> str:
    return concat("Hello", name)
```

When I run pytest, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_lib'

How is it that it can find my_app.py but can't find my_lib.py? They're in the same package. I've looked for solutions in the pytest docs and python documentation, but not much there about it. I played around with editing sys.path, but haven't been able to get it right. I put init.py files in both the my_app package and the test package, but that didn't change anything. Does anyone have a solution to this? Why is it so difficult to get unit tests to work in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with pytest and more a general question regarding python imports. It's tough to answer your question without knowing more info, but I would recommend resetting your path and doing some quick reading regarding absolute/relative imports to see if the answer becomes apparent.

However, if I had to guess, I would say this will fix your issue.

```
from my_app.my_lib import concat
```

Comment: I'm not sure were you're suggesting I import concat, bit I tried in the test file and it's obviously imported in my_app.py. But this import doesn't make a different. I'm still getting the same error. I've read about packages and modules in the docs, and nothing is really leading me to a fix.

Comment: Again, the question is why can my_app.py import my_lib.py successfully, and test_my_app.py can import my_app.py successfully, but pytest can't find that one dependency my_lib.py?

Comment: I recreated your structure locally and my intuition was correct.



In `my_app.py` you need to reference the absolute path I recommended above. Then pytest will pass successfully. Also ensure you still have the `__init__` files in both directories.

Comment: Did you try it in a virtual environment?

Comment: Hmm, definitely strange that I can't get this working like you did

Comment: no virtual env, simply an `__init__` in both directories and the reference to an absolute path as mentioned.

Comment: Forgot to give you the solution once I found out my issue. I had something in init.py that was breaking it. Once I took that out, your solution worked

Comment: It's rather confusing that Python works that way. You'd think that if the parent module can read a dependency, then importing the parent module in a test without the full path would work. Python's design seems a but kludgy in that regard

Answer (score 0):

Kept running into this issue myself.  First thing I got thru was pytest not being found.  Turned out I needed to run my console in Windows with "Run as Administrator...".  After that, and reinstalling "pip install pytest -U" one last time (not sure if that was needed but I did it anyways), pytest started working.

Then I added a `__init__.py` file in my tests folder.

```
some_project
---- my_app
     ---- my_app.py
     ---- my_lib.py
---- tests
     ---- __init__.py
     ---- conftest.py
     ---- setup_my_app.py
     ---- test_my_app.py
     ---- test_my_app.json
```

And `__init__.py` has this in it:

```
# Allows us to reference other non test_...py and ..._test.py py files in our tests folder and from the parent folder. 
# Allows us to reference non .py files, like .json files
import sys
import os
    
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
    
sys.path.append(currentdir)
sys.path.append(parentdir)
```

Then I run pytest from the "some_project" folder.  If you try to run it from the "some_project/tests" folder it won't work.  You can also run pytest from a parent folder of "some_project".  Not sure about needing `__init__.py` elsewhere with this solution.

At this point, pytest will import .py files from the root of some_project if there were .py files there as well as subfolder .py files.  It'll also allow you to reference non test_...py/..._test.py files, like regular py, json, etc files.

For example, in test_my_app.py I can have the following, then run `pytest` from the `\some_project` path:

```
import json
import pytest
import my_app
import setup_my_app


def test_something_super_important():
    with open("tests/test_my_app.json") as f:
        json_str = f.read()
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    assert 1+1 == 2
```

Comment: If you reference the absolute path like Teejay Bruno suggested, you should be able to run your tests from a parallel directory (package). Mine wasn't working with his suggestion, but it was because I had already made reference to the directory in init.py, so after I took that out, it started working. You should be able to do this without anything in init.py